# Is there a program that allows non-US/Canadian citizens to avoid going to secondary inspection when crossing the land border?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, i-94

I've started a job in Canada that requires me to drive to the US occasionally. At the border this week I've learned that apparently all non-US/Canadian citizens have to go to secondary screening to receive their I-94s. This is time consuming and annoying if you do this often.

Is there a program that would allow one to avoid this process and get stamped into the US without leaving the car?

Comment: Not technically an answer, but I believe holding on to your I-94 should mean you can avoid further processing until your VWP runs out. That should keep your annoying crossings down to 4 a year.

Comment: The best way is probably to apply for a long term US visa. That's allowable even if you are VWP eligible. Although it might be just as good to apply for Canadian PR.

Comment: @DJClayworth There's no point for a VWP national in getting a visa unless planning to stay for more than 3 months in one visit.

Comment: My understanding is that a 2 year visa would allow you to enter the US as many times as you like in those without having to go through the secondary processing required of a VWP applicant.

Comment: Land entrants needing an I-94 can only avoid secondary if they already have an I-94 from a previous entry valid for the duration of their stay. With a B visa the I-94's you get are generally valid for 6 months, versus 90 days for an I-94W, so a B visa can halve the frequency of secondary visits (even for day visitors); that's the advantage of a B visa over the VWP. The validity of the visa itself doesn't change the I-94 validity, however, that remains 6 months even for 10 year B visas.

Comment: @Dennis I've read that you can sometimes be admitted on a B visa for 1 year. When does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately all land border users who are not somehow exempt from the requirement to have an I-94 (i.e. American citizens and LPRs, visa-exempt Canadians and Bermudians and maybe BCC holders), and who do not already have an I-94 that is valid for the time to be spent in the US, will need to go inside to secondary and pay the $6 to get one. Once you have the I-94, however, you'll normally be admitted by primary inspection on subsequent trips, and perhaps be allowed to enter at Class B Ports of Entry, for as long as that I-94 is still valid. Once it expires you'll need to go inside to secondary to get a new one. A frequent VWP traveller can hence expect to visit secondary not (much) more than once every 90 days.

While an occasional visit to secondary is unavoidable a VWP traveller can reduce the frequency at which you have to do this to twice a year by applying for a B visa, as this extends the validity of the I-94s you receive to 6 months. It also permits extensions to be applied for while in the US if you are unavoidably delayed beyond the expiry of the I-94 you entered with.

I'm not positive how this all interacts with air travel but you may find that if you fly to the US and then subsequently enter by land you may be admitted by primary for the remainder of the (paperless) I-94 you received for the flight (I'd be interested to know if someone has experience contrary to this). If so, a mixture of land border and air travel might keep you out of secondary at the land border altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign but resident citizens (in Canada and the US) can qualify to get NEXUS, a trusted traveler card that helps save time when crossing the Canada/US border, or into either country from abroad.  You may want to do some research to see how your I-94 is affected by being a member, but it might save you some time.

Comment: That's for **permanent** residents of Canada, not temporary ones

Comment: I believe that even NEXUS card holders who need an I-94 but don't have (a currently valid) one need to go to secondary to get one. They might get to the primary inspection in a shorter queue, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way AFAIK, which only applies to VWP nationals (and AFAIK you're not one) is to get an ESTA. In this case, at major road crossings and the Vancouver train station, I've been told on the phone by the local CBP officers you'll not need to obtain the form.

Comment: Nope, ESTA nationals were traveling with me and they also had to get the form. But the train station has a US border post, so it is seamless regardless of your passport.

Comment: @JonathanReez Where did you cross? I've personally called the Blaine, Vancouver station and Rouses Point checkpoints and the supervisors said those having a valid ESTA don't need the form

Comment: At Blaine. We were asked to leave the car to go get our I-94s.

Comment: @Coke, You might have been asking the wrong question. I understand that those without ESTAs have to fill out the form while those with ESTAs just get a printed receipt (the OP might know for sure), so if you just asked about the form the answer you got might be strictly correct. Both have to go to secondary and pay the $6, however, and it is the visit to secondary, form or not, that is annoying.

Comment: @Dennis I asked whether ESTA holders have to pay for and obtain a form, and got a clear no. Again, can only speak for those crossings, but this was 4 months ago and I can't imagine this not having expanded since. What you mention was the case at the Niagara Falls in mid-2016, so I'm familiar with that variant too

Comment: I can't remember what happened in 2016, my most recent experience with an ESTA holder was last October at Osoyoos/Oroville. We went inside for her paper (I wasn't paying attention to see if the $6 changed hands). It apparently works that way at Blaine too. I'm not sure there are "variants".

Comment: @Dennis There are three variants: either the ESTA makes no difference and you have to get the form manually, or ESTA holders get a pre-printed form, or they just get stamped like at an airport. The first variant applied when entering by train from Montréal in summer 2016 (I called and asked), the second when entering by train from Toronto, and the third when entering by train from Vancouver, at Blaine and at Rouses Point by car/bus

Comment: Ah, yes, there are variants when traveling by a common carrier (whose ticket price might or might not include an immigration fee that covers the I-94 if needed, paper or not). Private car travel, however, seems quite uniform; if you haven't got a valid I-94 already you go inside and pay for one. The above suggests it works that way at Blaine, too.

Comment: @Dennis Didn't even know it ever made a difference whether you travel by bus or car at a given checkpoint

Comment: @Dennis Hm, just called Blaine again and now the officer indeed said there'll be a pre-printed I-94 form for ESTA holders. Didn't get to ask whether you have to pay for it though, as someone was collapsing in the background whereby he had to hang up - he told me to call back later. Also called Vancouver airport (same CBP as at the train station) - they said ESTA holders don't need the form at all at the train station

Comment: @JonathanReez you say they were "ESTA nationals": that's not the same thing as having a valid ESTA; it just means that they qualify to apply for it.  Did they actually have them?

Comment: @phoog yes both had them issued in advance. All of us paid $6 to enter the country.