# Does an Irish visitor to Canada need a visa for a day trip to the US?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, day-trips, irish-citizens

My wife and I are traveling to Canada from Ireland (We are Irish citizens). We would like to visit Seattle in the USA for one night. Will we need a visa? If we do where do we apply?

Comment: Get an ESTA https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta

Comment: @DumbCoder depends on how they are entering the USA.

Comment: Thank you Guys for your answers, We are visiting Canada for 3 weeks so would like to go to the USA for a night or two.

Comment: BTW assuming you are flying to Canada you need a canadian ETA for that.

Answer (score 14):

Are you going by land or by plane or boat?

If flying or going by boat you will need to apply for an [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) as you are Irish citizens, Ireland is a [visa waiver](http://www.esta.us/visa_waiver_countries.html) country. Certain ferry crossings count as land crossings though which I have pointed out further down in my answer.

If you are going by land you won't need an ESTA. You will be given an I-94W by the CBP officer when you get to the border.

> If you are a citizen of a VWP country, and you are traveling by land
>   to the United States, you do not have to apply for ESTA. If you are
>   coming to the U.S. by air or sea, you DO have to apply for ESTA. If
>   you are not a citizen of a VWP country, you are required to have a
>   visa, and therefore ESTA does not apply to you.

[link for more info](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/~/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta%3F)

**Edit:** as Henning Makholm pointed out

> VWP citizens do not need an ESTA to travel on the ferries between
>   Vancouver and Victoria, BC and Washington state.  They are treated as
>   a land border port.

[link to this info](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1258/~/esta---traveling-to-u.s.-by-land)

Comment: Your second paragraph could also read "if flying or going by boat you will need to apply for an ESTA as you are Irish citizens and Ireland is a visa waiver country."

Comment: yeah makes it more articulate @phoog

Comment: There is some debate as to whether or not an ESTA is required for rail travel between Washington and BC.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk can you elaborate?  The [federal regulations](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.5) are unambiguous in applying the ESTA requirement only to "each nonimmigrant alien intending to travel by air or sea to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP)."

Comment: @phoog see https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/78957/58919

Comment: Just to clarify the weird commas in the last quote, the only international ferry in Seattle is to Victoria, and it is privately operated (I don't know whether this matters). There are publicly supported ferries between Victoria and Washington, as well as all-BC and all-WA routes, and another private ferry between Victoria and Port Angeles.

Comment: An ESTA in not needed by land, **but** if you do have one, at many crossings you'll either not Need the I-94W form at all, or a pre-printed one will be isued

Comment: @HenningMakholm The BC ferry crossings into Washington, at least from Victoria and Vancouver, pre-clear US customs in Canada, too, which differentiates them from most US cruise ship traffic.

Comment: @Coke nope, ESTA holders still need to submit their fingerprints during the first crossing. We've discussed this previously here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108095/is-there-a-program-that-allows-non-us-canadian-citizens-to-avoid-going-to-second

Comment: @JonathanReez And I recently called various CBP checkpoints (again) and asked. Vancouver Airport (who also staff the Train Station), for example, said very clearly that they only require the form at all for VWP travellers if they don't have an ESTA

Comment: @Coke it's not about the form per se, but about the need to submit your fingerprints. The car checking booths are not equipped to do it, so you have to go in.

Comment: @JonathanReez Well you have to submit fingerprints at airports too. I know you Need to go to secondary, but that doesn't mean the ESTA makes no difference to the processing. Like I said, it depends on the crossing. For example taking the Train from Montréal to New York you'll have to fill out a form yourself, while at the neighbouring vehicle crossing an ESTA holder gets a pre-filled form.

Comment: @Coke but then do you really save any time?